# WordPress setcookie() not work in if/else statement

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to `setcookie` in `if/else` statement but simply not work.

Without an `if/else` statement the `set_user_cookie` function work correctly

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');


    function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    $exists = email_exists($_POST['my_field_name'] );
    $email = ($_POST['my_field_name']) ;
    if ( !$exists ){
        wc_add_notice( __('ایمیل وارد شده برای معرف اشتباه می باشد' ), 'error' );
    }
            else{

function set_user_cookie() {
    $school = "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv";
    setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);

}
}}
```

Comment: But there is no `if` statement in `set_user_cookie`! Why don't you insert it the way you were doing so we can see what can be wrong with it?

Comment: don't want to using `if` statement in `set_user_cookie()`. just want to run `set_user_cookie()` function in the `else` statement.
if you have another method to run that code, please answer a question @AlanMachado

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I didn't see the `else` clause

Comment: Use `wc_setcookie('name', 'value', 'expire', 'secure' )` , also not sure why you are using the `init` hook, when the `if` condition isn't met set the cookie using the `wc_setcookie` method.

Comment: That's work @Anand thanks again , please add answer to vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `wc_setcookie` function.

```
wc_setcookie('name', 'value', 'expire', 'secure' );
```

There's no need to use the `init` hook, you can set the cookie in the `else` part

```
if ( !$exists ) {
    wc_add_notice( __('ایمیل وارد شده برای معرف اشتباه می باشد' ), 'error' );
} else {
    wc_setcookie(.......) ; //set you cookie params
}
```